# How get element width by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what's the JavaScript code for the find the 's width?

(I want get width `.FixedBox` whit javascript no jquery, but my code don't work.)

```js
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox').offsetWidth);
```

```html
<div class="FixedBox">
    The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout width of an element. Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS width.
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].offsetWidth`

Comment: or use an id selector

Answer (score 2):

The **[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns NodeList you need to get element from collection to get **[`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)** property. Also put them inside window load callback to execute only after elements are loaded.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox');
  alert(ele.length ? ele[0].offsetWidth : 'no elements with the class');
}
```

```html
<div class="FixedBox">
  The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout width of an element. Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present,
  if rendered) and the element CSS width.
</div>
```

Comment: I use it in code and get this console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`

Comment: @Mehdi :  in case there is no element with class name `FixedBox` , then it will fire the air

Comment: I want to call code after an element has been created.How is it?

Comment: Yes, it ok, but how is it befor load window it getting `.FixedBox` offsetWidth ?(Get width before load DOM)

Comment: @Mehdi : I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].offsetHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$('.FixedBox').load(function () {
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width)
});
```

```js
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```html
<div class="FixedBox">
  The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout width of an element. Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present,
  if rendered) and the element CSS width.
</div>
```

Comment: I run it and get this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined`

Comment: I want to call code after an element has been created.How is it?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width)


});

Comment: with javascript, it is as?: `$('.FixedBox').ready(function() {alert(document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].getBoundingClientRect().wid‌​th) })` ???

Comment: replace ready with load.  
$('.FixedBox').load(function () {alert(document.getElementsByClassName('FixedBox')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width)});

Comment: I try in this here https://jsbin.com/diyenahafu/edit?html,js,output but it have error.